# reading files and averging, keeps asking for user input

Tags: java, file-io

I am supposed to ask the user for the name of the file, then read the file and average the numbers in the file, my program just keeps asking for the name of the file.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class A13_Average
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    getFile();
}

public static void getFile()
{   
    String name;
    int sum = 0;
    int num = 0;
    try
    {
                    //Gets the user to input name of file
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the name of your file: ");
        name = in.nextLine();
        //gets each line of numbers
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(name));
        input.nextInt();

        while(input.hasNextLine());
        {
                             //sum of the numbers
             sum += input.nextInt();
                             //number of numbers
             num += 1;
        }

        System.out.println("The average of your numbers is: ");
        System.out.printf("#0.00", (sum/num));
        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception i)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: " + i.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

This is the numbers.txt the file to test with:

```
10
84
39
93
34
14
11
33
88
83
28
97
75
49
32
69
80
95
48
19
33
85
48
20
48
22
87
72
9
55
14
21
79
94
40
99
90
1
1
66
38
76
59
57
29
29
32
71
 2
72
13
74
35
24
29
24
21
78
76
52
74
29
25
54
100
96
59
55
9
71
1
99
88
82
24
38
72
10
3
8
43
43
49
28
6
48
15
27
93
34
4
87
73
24
28
12
52
66
10
63
8
34
100
2
56
22
89
96
56
27
83
29
22
98
80
96
64
17
84
39
82
16
62
99
88
85
52
72
15
25
48
14
10
82
21
75
50
40
99
92
27
86
66
38
79
85
54
94
46
93
34
15
31
57
31
55
10
99
90
100
99
95
47
5
98
85
48
17
90
2
27
92
17
87
74
34
8
36
42
30
46
89
92
26
64
15
46
95
52
72
14
16
68
63
11
39
88
77
71
100
96
62
93
32
82
21
60
71
6
53
90
2
28
3
21
78
78
78
77
64
19
25
52
69
74
33
85
48
15
45
80
96
58
53
82
19
33
97
68
64
25
49
25
57
41
14
3
9
75
42
31
64
19
19
34
7
9
56
22
88
81
6
48
22
87
74
32
83
35
22
96
61
90
100
97
75
41
10
92
21
70
91
13
89
94
38
77
63
12
59
57
30
49
32
72
9
73
20
56
17
91
11
38
71
6
75
46
90
98
82
19
23
1
63
3
13
83
29
23
9
67
60
72
17
74
34
11
33
87
73
28
11
26
66
46
90
99
93
32
81
13
72
16
63
5
4
43
54
91
8
34
1
4
72
8
24
28
97
73
20
59
62
100
1
49
29
22
84
44
66
47
5
1
93
28
98
76
58
45
70
85
48
13
75
41
12
49
34
8
20
50
48
10
5
15
41
10
3
27
95
48
18
11
36
45
78
74
36
40
9
53
84
45
80
97
72
9
57
36
38
64
22
93
28
7
94
37
58
46
91
10
87
68
63
5
37
49
26
61
88
81
11
19
27
91
12
54
1
3
12
52
65
28
98
80
98
77
69
73
27
82
23
12
66
45
70
93
31
51
59
55
10
1
75
49
35
18
97
70
86
59
65
35
31
54
100
98
76
58
43
41
21
78
82
16
48
12
50
46
84
45
75
43
48
22
97
70
91
10
7
94
39
94
44
65
33
100
98
84
36
43
50
42
25
44
60
77
65
30
43
46
86
62
100
1
49
29
22
84
44
66
47
5
1
93
28
98
76
58
45
70
85
48
13
75
41
12
49
34
8
20
50
48
10
5
15
41
10
3
27
95
48
18
11
36
45
78
74
36
40
9
53
84
45
80
97
72
9
57
36
38
64
22
93
28
7
94
37
58
46
91
10
87
68
63
5
37
49
26
61
88
81
11
19
27
91
12
54
1
3
12
52
65
28
98
80
98
77
69
73
27
82
23
12
66
45
70
93
31
51
59
55
10
1
75
49
35
18
97
70
86
59
65
35
31
54
100
98
76
58
43
41
21
78
82
16
48
12
50
46
84
45
75
43
48
22
10
70
91
10
7
94
39
94
44
65
33
100
98
84
36
43
50
42
25
44
60
77
65
30
43
46
86
62
100
1
49
29
22
84
44
66
47
5
1
93
28
98
76
58
45
70
85
48
13
75
41
12
49
34
8
20
50
48
10
5
15
41
10
3
27
95
48
18
11
36
45
78
74
36
40
9
53
84
45
80
97
72
9
57
36
38
64
22
93
28
7
94
37
58
46
91
10
87
68
63
5
37
49
26
61
88
81
11
19
27
91
12
54
1
3
12
52
65
28
98
80
98
77
69
73
27
82
23
12
66
45
70
93
31
51
59
55
10
1
75
49
35
18
97
70
86
59
65
35
31
54
100
98
76
58
43
41
21
78
82
16
48
12
50
46
84
45
75
43
48
22
97
70
91
10
7
94
39
94
44
65
33
100
98
84
36
43
50
42
25
44
60
77
65
30
43
46
86
62
100
1
49
29
22
84
44
66
47
5
1
93
28
98
76
58
45
70
85
48
13
75
41
12
49
34
8
20
50
48
10
5
15
41
10
3
27
95
48
18
11
36
45
78
74
36
40
9
53
84
45
80
97
72
9
57
36
38
64
22
93
28
7
94
37
58
46
91
10
87
68
63
5
37
49
26
61
88
81
11
19
27
91
12
54
1
3
12
52
65
28
98
80
98
77
69
73
27
82
23
12
66
45
70
93
31
51
59
55
10
1
75
49
35
18
97
70
86
59
65
35
31
54
100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem

```
  while(input.hasNextLine());
```

Delete the `;`

```
  while(input.hasNextLine())
```

The `;` is an ending statement

Comment: thank you that fixed the nonstop asking for user input, but now its displaying error: null

Comment: What line are you getting that?

Comment: do you mean the [nextLine()] to [nextInt()] or [hasNextLine] to [hasNextInt]...(I'm new to java as you can tell.

Comment: No, I deleted that. I was looking at your code wrong. Where is the error occuring?

Comment: well it was returning null, after i delete the semicolon, but i changed the while loop to input.hasNextInt and now it is working, except i have to format it correctly

Comment: oh well I am trying to use print f format to format the average in decimal places

Comment: @user2723834 change your printf("#0.00", sum/num) with printf("%f", (sum/num). also, you might want to declare sum as double.

Comment: Use `printf("%.5f", sum/num);` the number after the `.` is the number of decimal places